# How do I store the line numbers in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

When I write some paragraph in a textarea and then submit it, it goes to the backend, where the whole paragraphs gets split into several lines. I want to store the line numbers of those split array into an array, how do I do it?

the api sends back data as such

```
{
  "sentence": [
    "Australia’s unexpected exit from the world cup has left all of us dismal and dejected.",
    "As we desperately search for that ray of sunlight amidst all this doom and gloom, even the weather seems to have forsaken us.",
    "The skies have darkened, as though in response to our collective anguish and the next weekend seems a million years away.",
  ]
}
```

you might be wondering why I want to do that. it's because I will also get line numbers from the api, and I will have to match a specific line number with the line number that I get from the api then replace a certain word in that specific line.

is this how to do it? i'm pretty new so please excuse for the naive mistakes

```
 const response = await fetch(url, options);
 const result = await response.json();
 const {
        lineNumber
      } = result.sentence[];
```

update:

here on line number 2, i will have to show a drop down and will replace the word 'collective' with 'inner' or 'constant' on clicking.

so what my website does is it will replace few words and the scores for emotions will change. Think this as grammarly where they are used to replace the words based on grammar, here it is emotion. I basically have a textarea where the user will enter some text and it will go to the api. then i will have textarea paragraph split into array and each line number will be associated with a line number. the api will also send the line numbers where the emotions need to be changed. so now we check if any line number from our paragraph matches with any line number send from the api, here in our case, it's showing line number 2, a words need to be replaced.

all i want is to check the line number from the 'sentence' array with the line number from the recommendation json object and then show an underline under the word that is in the recommendation json object, here it will be the word 'collective'.
i hope i was clear

```
"recommendations": {
    "anger": {
      "2": {
        "collective": [
          "inner",
          "constant"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: You don't really have to do that. Because the "lines" are already in an array, the array indexes naturally serve as the line numbers.

Comment: how do I check the line number from sentence with the line number from the api. i have updated the question with the line number sent from the api.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `map()` to convert the result into an array of objects with key/value pair:

```js
var result = {
  "sentence": [
    "Australia’s unexpected exit from the world cup has left all of us dismal and dejected.",
    "As we desperately search for that ray of sunlight amidst all this doom and gloom, even the weather seems to have forsaken us.",
    "The skies have darkened, as though in response to our collective anguish and the next weekend seems a million years away.",
  ]
}

result = result.sentence.map((s, idx) =>{
  return {text: s, lineNumber: (idx+1)}
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you also please help with the checking of line numbers? i have updated the post at the bottom

Comment: @henrydoe, the update part is not quite clear to me, how the main object is really formed with *recommendations*? Please update the question with minimum workable code with sample input and output:)